# Composite key with columns c1 int and c2 int, where c2 is IDENTITY with a separate series of values for every c1

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Lets assume we have a webshop with a table Orders.

It has the composite key

```
OrderID int, ShopID int
```

If I

```
insert into Orders (ShopID) values (3)
```

I want Order to contain:

```
OrderID ShopID
      1      3
```

and then

```
insert into Orders (ShopID) values (4)
```

it should contain

```
OrderID ShopID
      1      3
      1      4
```

and if I

insert into Orders (ShopID) values (3)

it should contain

```
OrderID ShopID
      1      3
      1      4
      2      3
```

without the hack of manually trying to insert records, increasing OrderID described in for instance

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/792a5b82-2d13-46bd-8650-a75a74ea222f/composite-primary-key-with-auto-increment-column

the reason of me thinking about this solution as a hack being that I did not have to manually insert records when I only had a single column and there is no logical reason I should need to resort to that kind of solutions with my specified requirements.

I am using T-SQL, and I have heard some rumour on irc about some version of it actually supporting this, but I dont know in which way.

The question of course extends to other RDBM:s.

Answer (score 3):

You're asking for something SQL Server can't provide. Now if OrderID was an IDENTITY then you'd get an get an autoincrement field so each insert will generate a new order ID. If this isn't what you're wanting, and you effectively only want OrderID to increment based on some other rule, then you're out of luck - you'll need to use business logic and manually manage the incrementing.

This latter should probably be avoided: manually tracking and deciding when to update is prone to races or serialised access (basically if two threads do a `SET @NewOrderID = (SELECT MAX(OrderID) + 1)` at the same time, they'll get the same result). An `IDENTITY` is probably going to be the better answer - it's not clear why you want each shop to have it's own run of OrderIDs.

In terms of the "I have heard some rumour...", I do wonder whether this is the ROW_NUMBER() with the PARTITION BY clause. This won't help you here: whilst you can have a SELECT statement restart a counter based on a given column, this is dynamic and it is not possible to guarantee that the row numbers generated on query 1 will be the same for the next query, depending on how rows are inserted and how you query (if you strictly control how rows are inserted, then you can gurantee - but this is a business rule and something SQL Server can't enforce).